# PHP Shorten IF statement

Tags: php, if-statement

So I have a variable we will say $string = 2;

if i want to check that variable for either 2 conditions I'd typically do 
if($string == 2 || $string == "Hello world"):

Is there anyway to combine these two args into something shorter like
if($string(==2 || =="hello world")):

I've googled this but I cant come up with the right phrase to get back the answer I'm looking for so explaining it at this point is the easiest.

Comment: If you were talking about more than two alternatives, it might make sense to use something like `in_array`

Comment: and what's the benefit, other than making it harder for the next person?

Comment: in_array() is a clever solution, but doing this solely to make the code shorter is misguided. Some languages such as Python provide such shortcuts. But I strongly suggest the long way in this case.

Comment: I find `in_array` nicer because it's less repetitive. Yes, the pure character count is longer, but that very much depends on your variable names as well. Also, if you already have two possible values you want to check against, chances are you'll want to extend that to three later, which is made trivial when already using `in_array`.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (in_array($string, array(2, 'Hello world')))
```

See http://php.net/in_array.

Comment: "Is there anyway to combine these two args into something shorter". I don't think you answered this question in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

A sick part of me wanted to answer this.

```
function f($a){
    $args = func_get_args();
    return in_array($a, array_slice($args, 1));
}
```

used like

```
if(f($str, 1, "hello world", 3, "etc")){
}
```

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu and this does it... f($str, args1, args2, ..., argsN) does what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

If variable have many states that can be processed in different ways, you can use `switch` statement:

```
switch($var)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
    //some action
    break;
    case 3:

    break;
}
```